# How to prevent std::string from using the initializer_list constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, list-initialization

I want the following code to output "test" instead of "X" for the case when using `std::string` using the same initialization as the other basic types. `std::string` now calls the constructor with an `initializer_list` and therefore the template specialization of `get` for `char` is called.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// Imagine this part as some kind of cool parser.
// I've thrown out everything for a simpler demonstration.
template<typename T> T get() {}
template<> int get(){ return 5; }
template<> double get(){ return .5; }
template<> char get(){ return 'X'; }
template<> std::string get(){ return "test"; }

struct Config {
    struct proxy {
        // use cool parser to actually read values
        template<typename T> operator T(){ return get<T>(); }
    };

    proxy operator[](const std::string &what){ return proxy{}; }
};

int main()
{
    auto conf = Config{};

    auto nbr = int{ conf["int"] };
    auto dbl = double{ conf["dbl"] };
    auto str = std::string{ conf["str"] };

    std::cout << nbr << std::endl; // 5
    std::cout << dbl << std::endl; // 0.5
    std::cout << str << std::endl; // 'X'
}
```

Is there a nice way of doing this without breaking the consistent look of the variable initializations?

Comment: @Praetorian why did you delete your answer?

Comment: My example worked on VS2013, but both clang and gcc reject it as an ambiguous call to `std::string`'s constructor, and I believe they're correct.

Comment: Use `{}` to construct an element from an element list (including one or zero), and `()` in all other cases.  This question is exactly why.

Comment: Gaaaaah. Why does `std::string` even HAVE an initializer list constructor? Who's going to write `std::string mystr{'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d'}`? I suppose you could be writing an initializer list of binary characters or something, but even then I'm not sure the initializer list would make that easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` has a constructor that takes an `initializer_list<char>` argument; that constructor will always be considered first when you use list-initialization with a non-empty braced-init-list, that's why the `char` specialization of `get()` is being matched.

If you use parentheses instead of braces for all the initializations, the `initializer_list` constructor will no longer be the only one considered in the `std::string` case.

```
auto nbr = int( conf["int"] );
auto dbl = double( conf["dbl"] );
auto str = std::string( conf["str"] );
```

However, this change alone doesn't work because you have an implicit user-defined conversion template that can yield any type. The code above, in the `std::string` case, results in matches for all `std::string` constructors that can be called with a single argument. To fix this make the conversion operator `explicit`.

```
struct proxy {
    // use cool parser to actually read values
    template<typename T>
    explicit operator T(){ return get<T>(); }
};
```

Now, only the explicit conversion to `std::string` is viable, and the code works the way you want it to.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b48cca0a191bdaf1)

Answer (score 2):

```
auto nbr = (int)conf["int"];
auto dbl = (double)conf["dbl"];
auto str = (string&&)conf["str"];
```

you have defined template operator T(), the above just calls it. to make a copy, you can

```
auto str = string((string&&)conf["str"])
```

**EDIT:** changed (string) to (string&&)

**EDIT2:** following works as well (tested them all - gcc -std=c++11):

```
auto nbr = (int&&)conf["int"];
auto dbl = (double&&)conf["dbl"];
auto str = (string&&)conf["str"];
```

Comment: either `(string)conf["str"]` or `string(conf["str"])` fails to compile on gcc

Comment: you are correct, we need (string&&)conf["str"] to match get<string>()

Comment: `(string&&)conf["str"]` breaks the consistency.